# Question Concerning Family of Trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have the following problem where I am asked to construct a family of trees (one for each $n$) that have exactly 2 leaves.

I am having difficulty with this problem mainly because I cannot find a definition for the phrase "family of trees".  I have searched online and through Rosen's 7th edition of Discrete Mathematics and have come up empty handed.  If someone could please provide a definition and perhaps a source, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a technical term; that’s why you don’t find a definition. *Set* or *collection* could be substituted for *family* without changing the meaning.

You’re being asked to show that for each $n$ (each $n\ge\text{something}$?) there is a tree (of height $n$? with $n$ vertices?) that has exactly $2$ leaves. The nicest way is to give a general construction that takes $n$ as input and produces the desired tree. (In fact the term *family* may have been chosen to push you in that direction, since it suggests a collection of things that are somehow naturally related.)